# How can I re-start the Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 2 wizard?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I started Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 2. Part way through installation, it ran into an problem accessing the database tier with the supplied credentials. It errored out at the 'Configuration Database' stage.

At this stage, we were at a partially updated state, so we had to roll back our TFS databases to the backup from before the update.  Once we finished this restore and ran the TFS Update 2 program again, it only offered the options to Repair or Uninstall...no option to continue where we left off.

How can I re-start the TFS Update 2 wizard?

BTW, Repair didn't do anything useful.

Comment: BTW...you'll also want to be sure to run the upgrade program TFS_Update.exe using an account that has access to all of the services and databases, even though the wizard does ask for additional credentials. If you don't, it may fail on running the Configuration Database step.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the answer. We had to rollback the server image and start from scratch to discover it, but after rebooting a prompt appears to run the upgrade wizard again. If you click the option to show details, it will show you that the command line is:

```
%PROGRAM_FILES%\TFSMgmt.exe resume UpgradeWizard /nosplash
```

This is from memory, so there may be slight errors.  I can't find this documented anywhere, if you know of a source please link to it.

Comment: `%PROGRAM_FILES%\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Tools\TFSMgmt.exe resume UpgradeWizard /nosplash`  <br/>
Or download and run the latest TFS Update installer (which reinstalls... then kicks off the first-run wizard).